# More pagination number links

Tags: pagination

As default EE seems to limit the page number links in pagination to 2 either side of the current page.

I normally change this in /system/codeigniter/libaries/paginatation.php in the $num_links variable.

I have just updated to EE 2.6 and gone to do this as I noticed the numbered links were back to default, and found that this variable is set as 10, yet only 2 either side are being displayed.

Does anyone know how to get more links in 2.6?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with the default pagination, however you can specify the number of links to show w/AB Pagination, see parameters for the {abp_pages} tag in the docs here: http://wedoaddons.com/addon/ab-pagination/documentation

If you still prefer to hack the default pagination, you'll need to edit the file system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Pagination.php

Disclaimer: I wrote AB Pagination

Comment: His link works great. I edited  private $_page_links_limit   = 6;